# node.js + express + handlebars render multiple views in a single request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to understand if I can render via the res.render() function or in some other way a multiple set of view(s).

In the home.handlebars I have the following code

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

and I want to replicate it into the default layout a "N" number of times.

After looking around as far as I understand the .render() function commits the entire transmission so if i write multiple res.render(); res.render(); is not going to work.

Am I approaching this from a complete wrong side or I am missing something? 
Do I need to create a "dynamic" view and than pass it one single time to the res.render()?

Thanks.

Attached code for test purposes:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout:'main' });

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8888);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
    res.render('home');
    res.render('home');
});


// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('express started on port:'+app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here is some code I use do help do that.  I have a partials directory inside of my views directory that I pull from.

Directory structure:

```
package.json
    /lib/app.js
        /templates/offering-links/handlebars
            /partials/offering-links-script/handlebars
```

Helper code to use the partials:

```
function partialsHelper (request, response, next) {
        response.renderPage = function (template, options, callback) {
            var partials = (options && options.partials) || {};

            partials.footer = path.join("partials", "footer");
            partials.header = path.join("partials", "header");
            options.partials = partials;

            //disable cache for dynamic content
            if (request.method === "GET") {
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            }
            // TODO: figure about max-age for cachable content

            return response.render(template, options, callback);
        };
        return next();
    }
    app.use(partialsHelper);
```

And then calling renderPage.

```
response.renderPage(
    "offering-links",
    {
        title: "Offering Links",
        offerings: offerings,
        partials: {
            script: path.join("partials", "offering-links-script")
        },
        baseURL: contextRoot
    }
);
```

Comment: Maybe I should point out that I'm quite new to node.js, i can grasp the reasoning behind the code but I definitely miss the definition of config.appVersion() and config.homeURL(). Since if i try to adapt the code to my example i get "config is not defined"

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. You can take that out.

Comment: I took those lines out of the answer

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but with this setup in the offering-links.handlebars you will have {{script}}, {{footer}} and {{header}}?

Comment: Yep. That's correct.  If you triple handlebars it will render the html. {{{header}}}.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm sorry but how is this working? I mean how is it that passing the object partials with the routes to the templates, implies the fetch and compile by the render function? I'm searching the web but there's almost nothing about the options object, even in the express docs all that says about it is that "is an object whose properties define local variables for the view"